# Search function in CRUD with C

Tags: c

I'm making a contact book in C and I've already done the parts of registering contact, listing all contacts and deleting a contact, but I need to elaborate the part of searching the contact, and also searching contacts that start with a given string, but I'm not succeeding... I'll leave my code below to see if anyone can help me identify where I'm going wrong:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    #define MAX_LENGTH 50

typedef struct
{
    char name[MAX_LENGTH];
    char number[MAX_LENGTH];
    int bd;
    char bdm[MAX_LENGTH];
} ContactBook;

void ListContacts(ContactBook **c, int quant)
{
    int i;

    printf("\n List of contacts: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d = birthday: %2d month %s\t name: %s \t number: %s\n", i + 1, c[i]->bd, c[i]->bdm, c[i]->name, c[i]->number);
    }
}

int addContacts(ContactBook **c, int quant, int size)
{
    if (quant < size)
    {
        ContactBook *new = malloc(sizeof(ContactBook));
        printf("\nenter contact name: ");
        scanf("%s", new->name);
        printf("\nenter number: ");
        scanf("%s", new->number);
        printf("\nenter the birthday ");
        scanf("%d", &new->bd);
        printf("\n enter the month birthday: ");
        scanf("%s", new->bdm);
        c[quant] = new;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n full list.\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

int deleteContact(ContactBook **c, int quant)
{
    int id;

    ListContacts(c, quant);

    printf("\n\t Enter the id you want to delete: \n");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    getchar();
    id--;
    if (id >= 0 && id < quant)
    {
        free(c[id]);
        if (id < quant - 1)
        {
            c[id] = c[quant - 1];
        }
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\t wrong code;\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

void SearchContact(ContactBook **c, int quant)
{
    int i;
    char searchedName[30];

    for (i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        printf("\n Search name: \n");
        scanf("%s", searchedName);
        getchar();

        if (strcmp(searchedName, c[i]->name) == 0)
        {
            printf("the name: %s was found", c[i]->name);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("name not found");
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    ContactBook *contacts[50];
    int option, size = 50, quant = 0;

    do
    {
        printf(" \n\t0 - exit\n\t1 - register contact\n\t2 - Remove contact\n\t3- List contacts\n\t4- Search contact\n\t");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        getchar();

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
            quant += addContacts(contacts, quant, size);
            break;
        case 2:
            quant += deleteContact(contacts, quant);
            break;
        case 3:
            ListContacts(contacts, quant);
            break;
        case 4:
            SearchContact(contacts, quant);
            break;
        }
    } while (option != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: you don't need the `getchar();` statements because all the `scanf` format specifiers you use filter leading whitespace automatically. You must watch out for `%c` and `%[]` but it's still not good to demand one single character *after* an input.

Comment: `void SearchContact(int quant, ContactBook **c)` should be `void SearchContact(ContactBook **c, int quant)`

Comment: Does your compiler not yield warnings for what @DavidRanieri points out? You should get at least a few (valid) warnings if you compile with all warnings enabled. I do with `gcc -Wall -Wextra` which is the absolute minimum you should be using IMHO

Comment: MS VC compiler yields 5 warnings and 1 error - fix them first. One fault is the absent function declarations.